# Fit image in a modal's div

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, bootstrap-modal

I have a little problem, I'm trying to fit my image in my modal's div.

This is what I have now and I want it to be like i draw in red

[What i have, in red is what I really want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbG01.jpg)

The original image is this, so you have an ideia real size

[Real image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgvRi.png)

My code right now is something like this .

**modal**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" onclick="hideModal()">&times;</button>
</div>

<!-- Modal Body -->
<div class="modal-body">
  <img class="modal-img" src="/images" >
</div>
```

**img **

```
<img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' onclick="showModal(this)" src="{$product.image}"  alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 1):

Give position relative to the parent div of the image and it will fit the modal. Some working example in [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/o3bhnvy0/1/)

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="modal-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgvRi.png" >
</div>

.image-container {
   position: relative;
 }

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; // or 100%
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link with a similar code to yours so I would be able to test it directly in your case?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/derxomk7/ i think there is missing something very important for you to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

Edit as per comments:

(I guess that you don't want to use the image as a background). You can style some bootstrap3 components:

```css
.modal-dialog {
  margin: 0; 
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; /*in case content overlap*/
}
.modal-body img {
  height: calc(100vh - 160px);  /* in order that both header and footer of .modal would be on the screen */
  width: auto; 
  margin: auto; 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgvRi.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

OLD Answer:

This happen since you are using `object-fit` **AND** declaring `width` and `height` to be 100%.

Maybe something like this:

```css
img{
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgvRi.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it did not worl, it only oppacipate background

Comment: Can you describe what is the desired result?

Comment: i want a modal that fit the screen and I dont need to scroll down to see the full image

Comment: @RicardoMartins -  Hope that i understand your desired result - Check edit please.

Comment: it did not work, do you have some skype or discord where i can share my screen with you and explain it better ?

Comment: the solution was give max-height: auto; to image to ajust to the div

Comment: @RicardoMartins glad you succeed to get your desired result (: